# Pass Data Back in MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, mapkit

I've tried to implement MVVM in a CoreLocation/MapKit project. My main view controller solely derives data from other classes(view models) and displays them. No thinking is done in the view controller.

CoreLocation and MapKit delegate methods are all done in separate classes which pass data to the view controller when the app has been launched.

After the app launches, a model class prepares a path to be drawn on the map when the user starts the process. Even though the path is determined successfully, the path doesn't get drawn since I can't pass data back from model to view-model(MapKit class).

Also even if I could pass data, the view controller already created the map view when the app launched and now it needs to redraw it.

So how can I pass data back from model to view-model and redraw my map view?

P.S. my coding of choice is Swift

Comment: You can use either delegation or NSNotification with your view model but IMO the MVVM pattern doesn't really work on iOS because there is no UIBinding. MVVM is popular in Windows where there is a UIBinding framework.

Comment: @Paulw11 Guess you're right. I started to feel the same. MVVM does not really work on iOS. Thanks for clearing my head out. Also would you consider writing your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use a delegation pattern to notify a delegate class that the model has changed or you can use `NSNotification`.  The latter works better if multiple observers need to know about updates.

In my opinion, however, the MVVM pattern doesn't really work on iOS because it doesn't support UI data binding, so the View-Model doesn't really buy you anything except for added complexity.  MVVM originated in the Windows world where there are UI data binding frameworks.